# Blank Ocean texture

Tags: displacement

I'm trying to use the ocean type texture for a displacement map. When I select type: Ocean from the texture dropdown the preview image is blank.

[image]

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think preview is supported for ocean textures

Comment: It is for ocean textures. I figured out what I was doing wrong. You have to create an ocean using the modifier first. Then you target that object to create the image. I guess there's not really a need to use that texture for displacement if the ocean modifier does this for you anyway.